# How could I "remove" installed "Tarball" version of Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi :)
i installed **Tarball** version of GAZEBO (gazebo-1.4.0.tar.bz2) from http://gazebosim.org/assets/distributions/ like http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.3/install on ubuntu 11.10 and Ros Fuerte. now **i wanna remove it** because I wanna install another version of GAZEBO (gazebo-dbg_1.4.0_amd64.deb). How can i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1683/how-could-i-%22remove%22-installed-%22tarball%22-version-of-gazebo?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Open a terminal, navigate to build directory, something like that: /home/user/code/gazebo-1.4/build

Run the command: make uninstall (with required privileges like sudo).

I hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2013-03-08**:
Somehow this never did anything for me.  I think it said no target called uninstall or something like that.

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-03-08**:
You must run the command in the folder that you ran the command cmake and make. It works for me.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-13**:
so then i think there isn't any unique answer!

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-03-13**:
Daniel is right. You should conserve the build/ directory from where you ran the "make install" in order to be able to uninstall files. Uninstall procedure needs to know some info coming from the moment of installation (like destination), so a clean clone of the repo it is not going to help.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/242/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-19**:
thank you :)